# contidional orderBy only on init AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

How can I run orderBy filter only once when my view is initialized? I don't want my list to be reordered during runtime.

```
<li ng-repeat="service in quote.services | orderBy:'index'" ></li>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the orderBy as a filter in your controller instead:

```
app.controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter){  
    $scope.quote.services = $filter('orderBy')($scope.quote.services, 'index');
}]);
```

See the [filter docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) for all the options.

Comment: Thanks, worked great. I'll mark as answer as soon as I can.