# AngularJS orderBy issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sorry if this sounds dumb.

I'm having a problem similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35615976/contidional-orderby-only-on-init-angularjs) and while the accepted answer worked, it also brought up another issue: When I add a new object to the array, Angular doesn't render it.

```
  app.controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$filter',
    'posts',
    function($scope, $filter, posts) {
      $scope.posts = $filter('orderBy')(posts.posts, '-votes')
    }
  ]
```

My add function:

```
    o.addPost = function(post) {
        return $http.post('/posts', post).success(function(data) {
          o.posts.push(data)
        })
    }
```

Are there anything I can do about it?

EDIT: I'm going with this:

```
  o.addPost = function(post) {
      return $http.post('/posts', post)
  }

  app.controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$filter',
    'posts',
    function($scope, $filter, posts) {
      $scope.posts = $filter('orderBy')(posts.posts, '-votes')

      $scope.addPost = function() {
        posts.addPost(param).then(function(response) {
        $scope.posts.push(response.data)
      })
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the factory just return the http instead of the unwrapping the promise inside the factory

```
o.addPost = function(post) {
    return $http.post('/posts', post);
}
```

then call the `addPost` method inside the factory.And catch the promise inside the promise.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$filter',
    'posts',
    function($scope, $filter, posts) {
        var params = {};
        posts.addPost(params).then(function(data) {
            $scope.posts = $filter('orderBy')(data, '-votes')
        })

    }
])
```

Comment: Good idea. Although there is a minor issue, you have to push the `data.data` inside the promise into `$scope.posts`. I want the filter to work only when the view initializes.

Answer (score 4):

angular only trigger for **instance changes**. If you just modify the array by `push` or `splice`, the filter won't be fired.

you can do the following way to give the `array` a new instance.

```
o.addPost = function(post) {
    return $http.post('/posts', post).success(function(data) {
      o.posts.push(data);
      o.posts = o.posts.slice();    // this will give array a new instance and fire the filter.
    })
}
```

Comment: I want the filter to work only when the view is initialized, not on subsequent add. That's why I don't use orderBy inside ng-repeat :D. Thank you, got it working now!